# Do power rings get resized for each user?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

Do the [power rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_ring_%28DC_Comics%29) in the DC Universe always need to be worn on a finger?

The rings are generally depicted to be of human-size, but throughout the universe lantern corps members could be of different size species and maybe without fingers. Does the ring automatically resize itself to the being?

For example: does the [Green Lantern Mogo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mogo) even have a ring?

[image: Green Lantern Mogo]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Rings automatically resize themselves for the appendage or body of the user. In the case of bodies without appendages, the ring resides inside the body of the wielder, as in the case of Mojo, for example.

Given the diversity of the Corps there are certainly aliens which do not have "fingers."

[image]